# CSS text-overflow ellipsis hover and reveal text in pop out box

Tags: css, overflow, ellipsis

I heard there was an attribute to display the contents of an `text-overflow:ellipsis` element in a pop out box (similar to excel's comments box??). Does anyone know how to achieve this - I only want it to effect the contents of cells in a table that have been 'ellipsed' and not for all elements you hover over.  My code is:

```
td, th {
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  // word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
  }

}
td:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  // white-space: normal;
  // word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use the popup from the [Title attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) as far I know there is no attribute like that you will need JS to create that pop out box.

If you want to use the **title** you can do something like this:

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
td:before {
  content: attr(title);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum nemo dolores tempora maiores expedita! Quod consectetur accusamus, enim asperiores quo, fugiat reiciendis quidem atque beatae magnam laborum molestiae quam voluptas!"></td>
    <td title="Quod consectetur accusamus, enim asperiores quo, fugiat reiciendis quidem atque beatae magnam laborum molestiae quam voluptas!"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: To be fair, the title attribute will work on its own! It is it's own pop up box! Doh! Cheers.